# How garbage collection takes place in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection

How garbage collection takes place in Python. Some people say that it happens automatically. But what is the proper process of it ?

Answer (score 7):

**Introduction to Python memory management**

Python's memory allocation and deallocation method is automatic. The user does not have to preallocate or deallocate memory by hand as one has to when using dynamic memory allocation in languages such as C or C++. Python uses two strategies for memory allocation reference counting and garbage collection.

Prior to Python version 2.0, the Python interpreter only used reference counting for memory management. Reference counting works by counting the number of times an object is referenced by other objects in the system. When references to an object are removed, the reference count for an object is decremented. When the reference count becomes zero the object is deallocated.

Reference counting is extremely efficient but it does have some caveats. One such caveat is that it cannot handle reference cycles. A reference cycle is when there is no way to reach an object but its reference count is still greater than zero. The easiest way to create a reference cycle is to create an object which refers to itself as in the example below:

```
def make_cycle():
    1 = [ ]
    1.append(l)

make_cycle()
```

Because make_cycle() creates an object 1 which refers to itself, the object 1 will not automatically be freed when the function returns. This will cause the memory that 1 is using to be held onto until the Python garbage collector is invoked.

**Automatic garbage collection of cycles**

Because reference cycles are take computational work to discover, garbage collection must be a scheduled activity. Python schedules garbage collection based upon a threshold of object allocations and object deallocations. When the number of allocations minus the number of deallocations are greater than the threshold number, the garbage collector is run. One can inspect the threshold for new objects (objects in Python known as generation 0 objects) by loading the gc module and asking for garbage collection thresholds:

```
import gc
print "Garbage collection thresholds: %r" % gc.get_threshold()

Garbage collection thresholds: (700, 10, 10)
```

Here we can see that the default threshold on the above system is 700. This means when the number of allocations vs. the number of deallocations is greater than 700 the automatic garbage collector will run.

Automatic garbage collection will not run if your Python device is running out of memory; instead your application will throw exceptions, which must be handled or your application crashes. This is aggravated by the fact that the automatic garbage collection places high weight upon the NUMBER of free objects, not on how large they are. Thus any portion of your code which frees up large blocks of memory is a good candidate for running manual garbage collection.

**Manual garbage collection**

For some programs, especially long running server applications or embedded applications running on a Digi Device automatic garbage collection may not be sufficient. Although an application should be written to be as free of reference cycles as possible, it is a good idea to have a strategy for how to deal with them. Invoking the garbage collector manually during opportune times of program execution can be a good idea on how to handle memory being consumed by reference cycles.

The garbage collection can be invoked manually in the following way:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

gc.collect() returns the number of objects it has collected and deallocated. You can print this information in the following way:

```
import gc
collected = gc.collect()
print "Garbage collector: collected %d objects." % (collected)
```

If we create a few cycles, we can see manual collection work:

```
import sys, gc

def make_cycle():
    1 = { }
    1[0] = 1

def main():
collected = gc.collect()
print "Garbage collector: collected %d objects." % (collected)
print "Creating cycles..."
for i in range(10):
    make_cycle()
    collected = gc.collect()
    print "Garbage collector: collected %d objects." % (collected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
ret = main()
sys.exit(ret)
```

In general there are two recommended strategies for performing manual garbage collection: time-based and event-based garbage collection. Time-based garbage collection is simple: the garbage collector is called on a fixed time interval. Event-based garbage collection calls the garbage collector on an event. For example, when a user disconnects from the application or when the application is known to enter an idle state.

**Reference:**

[Python garbage collection](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001537/references/r_python_garbage_coll.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Understand the internals of python garbage collection and how Instagram engineers achieved a performance improvement of 10% by tweaking it.

[do-you-know-how-python-cleanses-itself](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/do-you-know-how-python-cleanses-itself-shaleen-taneja)